# How to bind the same dynamic context menu to a dynamic number of user controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, binding, contextmenu

Imagine this:
You have a number of controls which you want to have a context menu, the same menu. That context menu will be dynamic and can change at any time. So you create a static class like this:

```
public static class EmployeeContextMenu
{
    private static ContextMenu EmployeeMenu { get; set; }

    static EmployeeContextMenu()
    {
        EmployeeMenu = new ContextMenu();
    }

    public static ContextMenu Get()
    {
        return EmployeeMenu;
    }

    public static void Set(List<String> employees)
    {
        EmployeeMenu = new ContextMenu();
        MenuItem mi;
        foreach (var item in employees)
        {
            mi = new MenuItem();
            mi.Header = item;
            EmployeeMenu.Items.Add(mi);
        }
    }
}
```

And at some point you need to change the menu items and use the Set method above, works perfectly fine.
Somehow you want to bind your controls context menu to the Get method.
Might be achieved like:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type local:EmployeeContextMenu}" MethodName="Get" x:Key="myCM" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Name="tb" ContextMenu="{Binding Source={StaticResource myCM}}" />
</Grid>
```

And of course you want the controls context menu to be updated as soon as the static Set method is called.

But above, something is basically wrong with the binding...no context menu shows up at all.
So how would you set the binding? Datacontext, datasource? Where and how?

It would of course work if you implement

```
tb.ContextMenu = EmployeeContextMenu.Get();
```

But that would be a bad solution if you have an unknown number of dynamically created user controls which you badly want to have the mentioned context menu which will be updated on the fly.

Comment: the binding looks OK, are you sure the `EmployeeMenu` is not empty? (we have to set the items via `Set` method first). Also if there is something wrong with Binding, you can try looking at the `Output` window, there should be some message there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you can do is to restructure it a bit as you need `change notification` for the `EmployeeMenu` property in order to update after `Set()` method

so start by the class itself

```
namespace CSharpWPF
{
    public sealed class EmployeeContextMenu : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private EmployeeContextMenu()
        {
            //prevent init
        }

        static EmployeeContextMenu()
        {
            Instance = new EmployeeContextMenu();
            Instance.EmployeeMenu = new ContextMenu();
        }

        public static EmployeeContextMenu Instance { get; private set; }

        private ContextMenu _menu;
        public ContextMenu EmployeeMenu
        {
            get
            {
                return _menu;
            }
            set
            {
                _menu = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("EmployeeMenu"));
            }
        }

        public void Set(List<String> employees)
        {
            EmployeeMenu = new ContextMenu();
            MenuItem mi;
            foreach (var item in employees)
            {
                mi = new MenuItem();
                mi.Header = item;
                EmployeeMenu.Items.Add(mi);
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

I have implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`
made it non static with private constructor to avoid init
sealed the class to prevent deriving further
added static `Instance` property to look from xaml

rest is quite basic

xaml

```
<Grid xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF">
    <TextBlock Name="tb" ContextMenu="{Binding EmployeeMenu,Source={x:Static l:EmployeeContextMenu.Instance}}" />
</Grid>
```

to call Set() method

```
EmployeeContextMenu.Instance.Set(list);
```

so the whole idea it to enable the property changed notification while keeping as static reference

Comment: I felt I needed any kind of notification but that can't be applied to a static class so I was stuck there. Your way, works perfect!